# Solving Systems of Equations

Tags: linear-algebra

$x+y+4z=6$

$x+2y-2z=8$

$7x+10y+10z=60$

I'm pretty sure this is a false inconsistent system and you can't solve and find what the variables are to get them to equal out all three equations

Yes, these are all part of one problem.

Can you solve $x,y,z$ and they work for each equation? Or is it false like I think it is?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you get stuck? Do you know about matrices and the gauss-jordan elimination algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x+y+4z=6\\
2x+4y-4z=16$$
$$5y=22-3x\\
10z=4-x$$
$$7x+10y+10z=7x+44-6x+4-x=48+0\cdot x=60$$
$$0\cdot x=12$$
$$\therefore \text{No solution}$$

Comment: Just curious, does the fact that this has no solution mean that these lines are all skew to each other?

Answer (score 0):

$$x+y+4z=6$$

$$x+2y-2z=8$$

$$7x+10y+10z=60$$

Subtracting equation $1$ and $2$ gives

$$-y+6z=-2$$

7 times equation 1 - equation 3

$$-3y+18z=-18$$

Divide the last equation by $3$ and you get a contradiction : $-y+6z=-6=-2$